# How to retrieve the result as JSON Arrray format in REST Response

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey

I am trying to retrieve the data from database and return them in 'Response' as JSON array. 
But now I am getting the result in browser as below, which is not the correct JSON array format. How can I receive the data as JSON Array ?

```
{"{\n  \"id\": 14,\n  \"name\": \"Test Doom Post\",\n  \"email\": \"test@test1.com\...
```

JDK 1.7
Jersey (jaxrs-ri-2.25.1) 
Gson

//Following is my Get method below:

```
@Path("/register")
public class JSONService {
    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response getRegisterInJSON() {

    JSONObject requestedJSON = new JSONObject();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        SoccerUtils dbConnection = new SoccerUtils();
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getWeekendDBConnection();    

        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT ID, FIRST_NAME, EMAIL FROM mycoolmap.weekendsoccer_login");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
        RegisterPlayer playerObj = new RegisterPlayer();
            playerObj.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
            playerObj.setName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
            playerObj.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));          

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();     
            String json1 = gson.toJson(playerObj);
            requestedJSON.put(json1, json1);            
            System.out.println(requestedJSON);                      

        }       



       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

       } finally {

       }

       return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(requestedJSON.toString()).build();


    }
```

// Register Player POJO class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RegisterPlayer implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;   


    public RegisterPlayer() {

    }

    public RegisterPlayer(int id, String name, String email)
    {
    super();

    this.id =id;    
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email; 

    }

    public int getId()
    {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {   
    this.id =id;        
    }
    public String getName()
    {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
    return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
    this.email = email;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RegisterPlayer[id=" + id +", name=" + name +", email="+ email +"]";
    }



}
```

Comment: Add objects to array to return array.

Comment: @RomanC: I did as per your comments and it worked !

Comment: Great! You can answer your question if you know the difference between json object and Json array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised by Roman in above comment, I have created a list, add the object and return the list. It worked as expected.

```
/Created a 'registerPlayerList'  List 
     List<RegisterPlayer> registerPlayerList = new ArrayList<RegisterPlayer>();
    //  Intialiaze the RegisterPlayer class
            RegisterPlayer playerObj = new RegisterPlayer();
    //set all the values into the object        
            playerObj.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
            playerObj.setName(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));
            playerObj.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
            ......
    //add the playerObj to the created registerPlayerList
            registerPlayerList.add(playerObj);

    // return the list      
            return registerPlayerList ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're printing the json to string (the `json1` variable), but you're adding that string to a JSONObject.  When a string is added to a JSONObject, the string will be escaped - that's a String json object.

If you print `json1` instead (and set that as the entity), it should work.